# Designing a generic library for calculating player turns in games

Tags: design-patterns, ooad, system-design

I was asked this question in an interview. 
Basically, I have to create a generic library which games can to use to calculate player turns.
I came up with this soln.

The library will define a *Player* class that needs to used by any game that was use the libraries turn calculation strategy.
The library has an abstract class named say *BaseStrategy* which has a *findNextTurn(List<Player>, currentPlayer)* method that can be implemented by child class strategies like *RoundRobinStrategy*, *PriorityBasedStrategy* etc

Our *GameController* will get an instance of the appropriate strategy by calling a *TurnStrategyFactory* and will call 
*strategy.findNextTurn(List<Player>, currentPlayer)* every time to get player whose turn is next.

The interviewer wasn't happy with passing the List & the current Player state everytime.

How can I solve this better?

Comment: Your list of players and the index of the current player can be stored in a singleton `GameState`

Comment: Hi. Even if I use a Singleton, I should still pass that every time I call strategy.findNextTurn(GameState) right? The interviewer was expecting calling findNextTurn() without passing any params

Comment: No. A singleton can be accessed globally. That's the pattern of it. Therefore, you access it inside the method, not from a parameter

Comment: Oh, fine. That makes sense.